# Photoshop cs6 error at the launch of the setup

Tags: adobe-photoshop

When I am trying to launch the standalone setup photoshop cs6 in my 64 bit windows * pc i am getting the following error

"Installer has detedted that machine restart may be pending. It is recommended that you may quit the installer, restart your machine and try installing again"

I restarted many times but still the same error. Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the installer is looking at a registry key.

In **regedit.exe**, navigate to

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager
```

There should be a key with the name, `InProgress`.  Delete it.

(As far as I know, deleting this registry value is quite safe.  But be careful nonetheless!)

---

### Reference

*Here's how to open the registry editor in Microsoft Windows.*

#### Windows Classic

In the Start menu, click on "**Run**".  Type "**regedit**" into the one-line box and click "**Open**".

#### Windows Aero

You can access the registry editor, regedit.exe, by clicking on the Start button and searching "**regedit**".  The first result should be a blue cube-looking thing.  Click it.

#### Windows Metro

In the Start screen, search for "**regedit**".  The first result under "Apps" should be the registry editor.  Click it.

Comment: Aero is not a Windows version!

Comment: @Karan *Correction:* I've regrouped the reference categories into interfaces now.